# Jasmine- Object Property toBe() Incorrect

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

In this piece of code:

```
var disable = { inputLabelBox : false, nodeIpInput: false, checkBox: false};

  var checkDeviceNameExists = function(devices, form) {
    return devices.some(function(element) {
        nameExists = deviceNameMap(form, element);
        if (nameExists) {
            form.address.$setViewValue(nameExists);
            form.address.$render();
            if (!disable.checkBox || !disable.nodeIpInput) {
                disable.checkBox = true;
                disable.nodeIpInput = true;
                checkBox.checked = false;
            }
            console.log(disable.checkBox);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
  }
```

Everything works out as it should, but I can't get the `expect(disable.checkBox).toBe(true);` to work. I get `Expected false to be true` instead. I have verified the `console.log(disable.checkBox);` is true. Any suggestions?

```
  beforeEach(function() {
    form = {};
    form.label = {};
    form.address = jasmine.createSpyObj("address", ["$setValidity", "$setViewValue", "$render"]);
    form.$setValidity = jasmine.createSpy("$setValidity");
    disable = { inputLabelBox : false, nodeIpInput: false, checkBox: false};
  });
  it("It should populate ip address because Vip label pre-exists", function() {
    form.label.$viewValue = "myvip";
    FormDeviceExistSvc.checkDeviceExists(form, "checkForVips");
    expect(VipSvc.getVips).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(form.address.$setViewValue).toHaveBeenCalledWith("10.11.11.1");
    expect(disable.checkBox).toBe(true);
  });
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a `console.log()` in your "beforeEach" callback?

Answer (score 0):

```
  it("It should populate ip address because Vip label pre-exists", function() {
    form.label.$viewValue = "myvip";
    FormDeviceExistSvc.checkDeviceExists(form, "checkForVips");
    expect(VipSvc.getVips).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(form.address.$setViewValue).toHaveBeenCalledWith("10.11.11.1");
    expect(FormDeviceExistSvc.disable.checkBox).toBe(true);
    expect(FormDeviceExistSvc.disable.nodeIpInput).toBe(true);
    expect(FormDeviceExistSvc.checkBox.checked).toBe(false);
  });
```

I needed to use full service name `FormDeviceExistSvc` to access the value `FormDeviceExistSvc.disable.checkBox`.

Also, note: In testing, you only want to test what is public, not private. So... anything from  the service that is `return {}` can be tested.